# Install Missing man (5) Page for nginx

Tags: ubuntu, apt, nginx, man

How can I install the [man 5 page for nginx.conf](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.5/nginx.conf.5)? It seems that this hasn't been made available when I installed the webserver through my package manager `apt` (`apt install nginx-full`).

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
```

```
root@host1:~# apropos nginx
nginx (8)            - "HTTP and reverse proxy server, mail proxy server"
```

I am studying for the [`LFCS`](https://training.linuxfoundation.org/certification/linux-foundation-certified-sysadmin-lfcs/) exam. Man pages are allowed. Most study materials teach things falling under the category `Configure an HTTP server` with `apache2`. I prefer to use `nginx` but admittedly look up the directives online. This can't be don't during the exam. So either there is a one-shot command to make the man page locally available or I am pretty lost ;).

`apt-get install --reinstall` doesn't make the man page available either.

Comment: But the assignment specified apache2

Comment: No, the outline specifies HTTP-Server. Nginx is an HTTP-Server. This is a performance based exam and was just a side-note. I am asking how I can make the nginx.conf man page available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nginx.conf man page you linked is for OpenBSD 5.5 (released in 2014) and based on the same site, it was [removed in 5.7](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.7/nginx.conf.5). This man page is not part of the upstream (and based on git history never was) so it's not available in Ubuntu. It was probably added by OpenBSD as a downstream patch, see the AUTHORS section:

> The bulk of the text was semi-automatically converted from the XML sources of http://nginx.org/en/docs/#development to mdoc(7) by Florian Obser florian@openbsd.org. The description of the grammar was written by Ingo Schwarze schwarze@openbsd.org.

Comment: Ouch this essentialy means that there is no man page for the nginx.conf file? I know that this is not the answer that I asked but is there any alternative to access directive documentation on the CLI?

Comment: There are some conf files examples in `nginx-doc`, but it doesn't cover everything.